# How to convert a 10G JSON file to Avro?

Tags: json, avro

I have a roughly 10G JSON file. Each line contains exactly one JSON document. I was wondering what is the best way to convert this to Avro. Ideally I would like to keep several documents (like 10M) per file. I think Avro supports having multiple documents in the same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Avro tools' `fromjson` command (see [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/) for more information and examples). You'll probably want to split your file into 10M chunks beforehand (for example using [`split(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a large JSON file to Avro is using avro-tools from the Avro [website](http://avro.apache.org/releases.html#23+July+2014%3A+Avro+1.7.7+Released).

After creating a simple schema the file can be directly converted.

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar fromjson --schema-file cpc.avsc --codec deflate test.1g.json > test.1g.deflate.avro
```

The example schema:

```
{
        "type": "record",
        "name": "cpc_schema",
        "namespace": "com.streambright.avro",
        "fields": [{
                "name": "section",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Section of the CPC"
        }, {
                "name": "class",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Class of the CPC"
        }, {
                "name": "subclass",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Subclass of the CPC"
        }, {
                "name": "main_group",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Main-group of the CPC"
        }, {
                "name": "subgroup",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Subgroup of the CPC"
        }, {
                "name": "classification_value",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Classification value of the CPC"
        }, {
                "name": "doc_number",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Patent doc_number"
        }, {
                "name": "updated_at",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Document update time"
        }],
        "doc:": "A basic schema for CPC codes"
}
```